# Can't access Hbase through Hue

Tags: hbase, hue, cloudera-quickstart-vm

So, I'm trying to access HBase through Hue browser in Cloudera VM, but I'm running into a few problems. First when I open  the Hue, I get this error :

```
Potential misconfiguration detected. Fix and restart Hue.
HBase Browser   Failed to authenticate to HBase Thrift Server, check authentication configurations.
```

When I goto the Hbase in Hue, I get this error:

```
Api Error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='quickstart.cloudera', port=9090): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2ef8ace450>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

I checked in Cloudera quickstart UI in browser and saw that Hbase Thrift server instance was down, so I tried restarting it, but it fails to restart.

In the Hbase configuration

```
hbase.thrift.security.qop was set to auth
```

So, I set it to none, restarted the Hbase and Hue, and now the Hbase thrift server was up. Then I went to Hue browser, but it showed error

```
Potential misconfiguration detected. Fix and restart Hue.
HBase Browser   Failed to authenticate to HBase Thrift Server, check authentication configurations.
```

When I go to Hbase, it shows

```
api error <html>
```

I tried every thing available on google like 
checking both

```
hbase.regionserver.thrift.http
hbase.thrift.support.proxyuser
```

But even after trying everything, I error didn't go away and I can't access Hbase through Hue.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!

Here's what I did.

I disabled all the services in the cloudera quickstart browserUI. I then enabled, HBase, then Hue and then Zookeeper. 
The changed all the Hbase settings to default like **authentication to none** and unchecked **hbase.regionserver.thrift.http** and 
**hbase.thrift.support.proxyuser**

Answer (score 0):

1. check the Hue Server logs http://x.x.x.x:8889/hue/logs
2. enable

> hbase.regionserver.thrift.http
>   hbase.thrift.support.proxyuser

3. add the config into the hdfs core-site.xml

> ```
>      <property>
>              <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hbase.hosts</name>
>              <value>*</value>
>      </property>
>      <property>
>              <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hbase.groups</name>
>              <value>*</value>
>      </property>
> ```